# How to Rename class name, val .... in IntelliJ once and done for all project

Tags: intellij-idea, rename

i have a project on IntelliJ and the name of the classes, Val, Package is in a language not the same for the language I want,
My question is for knowing if there is a solution for Example rename a function in one placement and automatically changing in all using to avoid errors while compiling
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the name of the variable/function and select [refactoring > rename](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html). You can also use a shortcut for this which is depending on your configuration (default being Shift + F6).

According to JetBrains, the creator of IntelliJ:

> Use the Rename refactoring to change names of symbols, files, directories, packages, modules and all the references to them throughout code.